# Guess the image game, Random Image generator without repetition

Tags: java, android, image, arraylist, random

I wanna make image guessing android game, there are 150 images, I want the image to be generated randomly, and the user should type the name of character if it is correct the next button will display another image till the 150 are finished

This the code for avoiding image repition

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(R.drawable.myImage);
int position = new Random().nextInt(list.size());
imageViewObject.setImageResource(Integer.intValue(list.get(position)));
list.remove(position);
```

but how should I compare the user input with character name, should I use image path, or make array for answers and compare it to user input?

Comment: Maybe create a class with image path and valid character name, make some functions to easily add new content

Comment: Okay I will try it thank you, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, depending on your project. An effective one would be storing them in an object (let's call it `Card`), and card will contain as properties (`imageURL` as String / `characterName` as String/ `ifCorrect` as Boolean).
Store these objects inside an array and if the user guesses the right answer, change the object's `ifCorrect` field to `true`, so you know the image has been played.

Comment: Yes, this will be a good way, thank you.